# Query Returning All Data In Table

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to figure out why this query is returning all of the data in the table:

```
State IN ('North Dakota') AND ('Homicide Offenses' > 0 OR 'Assault Offenses' > 0)
```

I've included the code I used to generate this statement below. The code works for single searches such as:

```
State IN ('North Dakota') AND 'Homicide Offenses' > 0
```

But does not work for anything else. Thank you for any insight you can give.

```
function getWhere() {
    var caps = getCAPS(); //Returns an array of user selections
    var states = getStates(); //Returns an array of selected states
    var where = "State IN (" + states.join(",") + ')';

    if (caps.length) {
        if (caps.length == 1) {
            where = where + " AND " + caps.pop();
        } else {
            where += " AND (";
            while(caps.length) {
                if(caps.length == 1) {
                    where += caps.pop() + ")";
                } else {
                    where += caps.pop() + " OR ";
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    return where;
}
```

Comment: I should also add that this is utilizing the google fusion table api.

Comment: these two columns Assault Offenses and Homicide Offenses, why did u put space into them? If these are value then
('Homicide Offenses' > 0 OR 'Assault Offenses' > 0) should return true always

Comment: `'Homicide Offenses' > 0` does not make _any_ sense whatsoever. `'Homicide Offenses'` is a character string, why do you compare it to _number_?

Comment: I used the single quotes because it is a column name that includes a space in the name but the values in that column are all numerical.

Comment: I'm using google fusion table api to hold the data.

Comment: Jahirul, could you please explain why these would return true if both of them were 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of
`State IN ('North Dakota') AND ('Homicide Offenses' > 0)` and
`State IN ('North Dakota') AND ('Assault Offenses' > 0)`
do actually work as expected, I'd check, whether

> <filter_condition>
>    A Boolean expression (returns TRUE or FALSE). Only table rows where the condition is TRUE will be included in the results of the SELECT. Use AND to combine multiple filters into a single query. [...] OR is **not** supported.

(from [Fusion Tables REST API - Row and Query SQL Reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference)) is really to be read as: No **`OR`**. (... and whether it leads -when ignored- to the observed effect.)

(This "OR is **not** supported" appears in both, the `SELECT` and the `CREATE VIEW` `<filter_condition>` sections of the document...).

Comment: Thank you, I read that wrong when I went over the documentation. It's always helpful to have another set of eyes. Back to the drawing board I go.

Comment: From the documentation, it doesn't seem to be possible to circumvent it along `('Homicide Offenses' + 'Assault Offenses' > 0)` either, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately not and the only other way to accomplish this that I can see is to create very cumbering workarounds like creating a new table and unioning everything or creating layers for every single checkbox.

Comment: With no `NOT`, you can't do `AND NOT ('Homicide Offenses' = 0 AND 'Assault Offenses' = 0)` either. Perhaps you can [Use formulas in columns](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/178196?hl=en) - putting the summed up value into a view, from which to select instead...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the error in the code, but try this to see if it fixes it. Just add the offenses together using a join like you do with the states, and check if the sum is > 0.

```
function getWhere() {
    var caps = getCAPS(); //Returns an array of user selections
    var states = getStates(); //Returns an array of selected states
    return where = "State IN (" + states.join(",") + ") AND " + caps.join("+") + " > 0"
}
```

You will need to change getCAPS to return a list of simply

```
"'Homicide Offenses'"
```

and not

```
"'Homicide Offenses' > 0"
```

which is probably the better way to do it anyway.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know what happens, thank you for the input.

Comment: Apparently OR isn't supported with the API. Thanks for your input, I'm putting together a new query now.

Answer (score 0):

Are these columns or values within a column? It may be that you need to change the where statement to something like the below:

```
State IN ('North Dakota') AND Offence IN ('Homicide Offenses' , 'Assault Offenses')
```

Comment: 'Homicide Offenses' and 'Assault Offenses' are both column names with numerical values.

Comment: Ah ok scrub my suggestion then!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
'State IN ('North Dakota') AND ('Homicide Offenses' > 0 OR 'Assault Offenses' > 0) AND STATE IN ('North Dakota')'

This should work for you I guess.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll give it a shot as well as the other recommendations I got and let you know.

Comment: Apparently OR isn't supported with the API. Thanks for your input though, much appreciated.